# Number theory question involving divisor and totient functions

Tags: number-theory

Given that $d(\phi(n)) = 2017$.
Find the smallest natural number $n$.
Here $d()$ represents the divisor function and $\phi()$ represents the totient function.
This question is from RMO 2017, Maharashtra and Goa region, India.

Comment: Do you know how the divisor function and totient relate to the prime factorization of the argument?  That is critical to questions like these.

Comment: I know about the totient function but not a clue regarding the divisor function which was why I got stuck up in the exam.

Comment: You could look at the line that defines $\sigma_0$ [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisorFunction.html)

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $2017$ is a prime number.

Number of factors of a number
$n={p_1}^{k_1} .{p_2}^k_2 ....{p_m}^{k_m}$ given $p_1, \ p_2,....\ are \ prime$ is $(k_1+1)(k_2+1)...(k_m+1)$

So comparing this we get $k_1=2016, \ k_2=....k_m=0$

I came to the fact that it isn't that obvious what n will be.

so we have $\phi(n)={p_1}^{k_1-1}.(p_1-1)...{p_m}^{k_m-1}.(p_m-1)=2^{2016}$

P.S check for silly mistake.
Thanks to @ErickWong for the edits

Comment: The last part is not obvious.  It is also incorrect: $\phi(2^{2016})$ is $2^{2015}$, so you should take $n=2^{2017}$.  However, it is not at all clear that this is the **smallest** value of $n$, since for instance, the smallest solution to $\phi(n) = 2^8$ is $n = 2^8+1$, not $n=2^9$.

Comment: that's were we can use the fact that 2017 is prime

Comment: No, you already used that to determine that $\phi(n) = p^{2016}$.  It’s not too hard to show that $p=2$ (but it still requires justification), but you haven’t given a single reason why there isn’t a smaller value of $n$ that works.  For example, what is the smallest value of $n$ such that $\phi(m) = 2^6$?  It’s not $n=2^7$, despite $7$ being prime.

Comment: In fact, you will be hard-pressed to find any two-digit value of $k$ such that the least solution to $\phi(n) = 2^{k-1}$ is $2^k$.  If you can only give vague reasons for why it’s obvious, then it probably doesn’t merit being called “obvious” :).  In this case there is actually considerable evidence against your claim (I do think it is true but requires *considerable* justification).

Comment: $\phi(n)={p_1}^{k_1-1}.(p_1-1).{p_2}^{k_2-1}.(p_2-1).....{p_m}^{k_m-1}.(p_m-1)$ 

so if its value is $2^{2016}$ so what can you( @ErickWong) say about $p
_1, \ p_2,......p_m$ ?

Comment: guys please don't downvote the answer, tell me where I am wrong

Comment: I have already told you twice what is wrong.  Find the other solution of $\phi(n)=2^6$ and you will see the gap in your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Now, $d(\phi(n))=2017$. The smallest such number who has divisors equal to $2017$ is $2^{2016}$, since $2017$ is prime. So, $\phi(n)=2^{2016}$. So, $2^{2016}< n \le 2^{2017}$. We can thus see that $2^{2017}$ is the smallest such number.